# Another confusion about initial condition in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am still having some confusion on certain problems.

Here is what I mean, the questions asks to solve the IVP and determine how the interval on which the solution exists depend ends on the initial value y_o.

For one the problems,

$$y'=2ty^{2}$$ $$y(0)=y_o$$

So I have no issue solving this via separation of variables and I get $$y=\frac{1}{d-t^2}$$

solving for d gives, $d=\frac{1}{y_o}$ that is $$y=\frac{1}{(1/y_o)-t^2}$$ so I understand that we can't have $y_o=0$ or we would have a  division by zero issue.

But here is my issue, the solution says that is correct if $y_o \neq 0$, but also says $y=0$ if $y_o=0$ but I just don't understand this. What is this from, where do they get this from? Can someone please help to explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $y_0=0$ then you cannot separate variables: doing so divides by zero at some step, and you get garbage. This happens regardless of whether you write it as $\int \frac{dy}{y^2} = \int 2t dt$ or more formally as $\int \frac{1}{y^2} \frac{dy}{dt} dt = \int 2t dt$.

The fact that there is a constant solution when $y_0=0$ is clear: if $y \equiv 0$ then $y' \equiv 0$ and $2ty^2 \equiv 0$ so $y'=2ty^2$ (the function satisfies the equation) and $y(0)=y_0=0$ (the function satisfies the initial condition). It is not so obvious that this is the only solution with $y_0=0$, however.

For the original question, the point is that if $y_0 > 0$ then eventually $1/y_0 - t^2 = 0$; past this point the solution will not exist.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems that y=0 will very often be a solution to first order equations like this then?

Comment: @Quality It doesn't really have anything to do with being first order: if you add 1 to the right side then nothing of this sort happens. You'll have $0$ as a solution to $y'=f(t,y)$ if $f(t,0)=0$.

Comment: So are you saying that because we can't divide when y=0, the only possible solution we could have when y=0 is 0?

Comment: @Quality That's actually not necessarily the case. For instance, $y'=3y^{2/3},y(0)=0$ has many solutions. One of them is the constant solution, but $x^3$ is another solution. There are many more, too. This is why I said it is not so obvious that the solution to your problem is unique. It turns out that it is, because your right side is locally Lipschitz continuous in $y$, whereas the right hand side in my example is not. But this is not so easy to prove.

Comment: Thank you, well would you have any suggestion then on what I should do to understand it as such? Because Lipschitz continuity is definitely not something we have or will cover in the course ( it is intro undergrad)

Comment: @Quality Sure, that's what I expected, I just didn't want to say anything factually incorrect. Basically you just need to be careful when you divide by $y$ in solving separable equations, because it won't work if your solution ever hits $y=0$.

Comment: @Quality Note that the form of the existence-uniqueness theorem in elementary ODE is just a slightly weaker version of the general one, where instead of Lipschitz continuity in $y$ you have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is continuous on a rectangle. This then implies that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is bounded, which by the mean value theorem furnishes the Lipschitz continuity used in the more general theorem.

Comment: Yes exactly, the thereom intended for us to use is that with the partials and rectangle

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$y=0$ is an obvious solution for the given differential equation. Whan you separate the variables you divide by $y^2$, so you have only solutions $y\ne 0$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks I think I was confused because I thought we were already assuming y was not zero when we first divided.

Comment: @Quality You were, but that assumption is not necessarily justified, and indeed it isn't justified if $y_0 = 0$.

Comment: @emilio Novati,  and thanks for your input, but I understand that we can't have y to be 0, but then what is mean by the book saying y=0 is a solution as well when y_o is zero

Answer (score 0):

You can still get the solution for $y_0=0$ from your solution formula by transforming it a bit
$$
y(t)=\frac{y_0}{1-y_0t^2}
$$
which is completely valid for $y_0=0$ as the denominator then is constant $1$.

Comment: Thanks, but can you comment if you have time why this implies y=0

Comment: Well, the numerator of the formula is 0, the denominator 1, thus the quotient 0, independent of the value of $t$.